# Center a div, expand sibling divs to remaining space

Tags: css, layout, html

I'm attempting to center a div and fill in to the left and right with divs.

The center div will be text of variable length, and the sibling divs will be lines filling in the available space.
Here's what I envision it looking like:

[image: mockup]

Here's the markup:

```
<div class='heading'>
  <div class='lines'></div>
  <div class='heading-link'>
    <a>Link Text</a>
  </div>
  <div class='lines'></div>
</div>
<div class='heading'>
  <div class='lines'></div>
  <div class='heading-link'>
    <a>Really Long Link Text that is still centered</a>
  </div>
  <div class='lines'></div>
</div>
```

Here's the barebones css:

```
.lines {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.heading-link {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

The key point is that the text in `.heading-link` is variable in length, and I would like the `.lines` divs to fill the remaining space to the left and right of `.heading-link`

I don't want to set a percentage width on `.heading-link` because I don't know how wide the text will be.  Should I be using a table based layout?  Or just inlined divs?

Comment: Added closing tags for `.heading`.  The `.lines` are meant to be duplicated.

Comment: I think I see what you are asking about but could you add an example to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution Using CSS Tables

The following might be close to what you need.

Your **HTML** is good as is:

```
<div class='heading'>
    <div class='lines'></div>
    <div class='heading-link'><a>Link Text</a></div>
    <div class='lines'></div>
</div>

<div class='heading'>
    <div class='lines'></div>
    <div class='heading-link'> <a>Really Long Link Text that 
        is still centered</a></div>
    <div class='lines'></div>
</div>
```

Try the following **CSS**:

```css
.heading {
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    margin: 30px 0; /* for demo only */
}
.lines {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 48%; /* the exact value is not that critical... */
    border-top: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
}
.heading-link {
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: nowrap; /* keeps the text from wrapping... */
    padding: 10px 20px; /* for demo only, as needed... */
}
```

**How This Works**

Apply `display: table` to the parent container `.heading`, and then `display: table-cell` to the child elements `.lines` and `.heading-link`.

I am using the table display type to take advantage of the auto-sizing features of table cells.

I am assuming that your `.heading-link` text will fit on one line, so I force the text to stay on a single line by using `white-space: nowrap`.  This will force the `.heading-link` element to expand to contain the text.  You can use padding to control the white space as needed.

For the left and right `.lines` elements, set the with to be something like 48%. This will keep force the left and right `.lines` elements to compute to the same width, half of whatever space remains after the space used up by `.heading-link`.

You can also specify an overall width to `.heading` if needed.

Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/eyGdG/

Comment: Brilliant! I don't normally use the table display type but it works well. Thanks.